# How to calculate the trace of a matrix in Keras backend?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, keras

I am implementing a custom loss function in Keras, and I need to perform a matrix multiplication and then get the trace of the resulting matrix. I could go one of two ways, both of which are giving me trouble in Keras:

**Option 1**: Iterate over the rows ( and columns ) of the 2 matrices. They both have the same shape, and sum the dot products of the corresponding rows and columns:

```
# Define custom loss
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    batch_size = y_true.shape[0]
    X = K.log( K.dot(y_true, K.transpose(y_pred) ) )
    y = 0
    for i in range(0,int(batch_size)):
        y -= X[i,i]
    return y
```

Error:

> File "neural_net.py", line 71, in custom_loss
>       for i in range(0,int(batch_size)): TypeError: **int** returned non-int (type NoneType)

Strange that the shape of the matrix is returning none.

**Option 2**: Just do the matrix multiplication and get the trace of the matrix:

```
# Define custom loss
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    X = K.log( K.dot(y_true, K.transpose(y_pred) ) )
    return -np.trace(X)
```

Error:

> return asanyarray(a).trace(offset=offset, axis1=axis1, axis2=axis2,
>   dtype=dtype, out=out) ValueError: diag requires an array of at least
>   two dimensions

I am fairly certain that X is a 2-d matrix. My batch size is 32 and there are 47 nodes in the output layer. I've seen output showing that both the matrices are 32 x 47, so the dot product is definitely 2-D. But i was reading that there are some issues about accessing the size of the matrices and using numpy operations inside the keras backend, so I was hoping to find a `trace` function in the keras backend but was unable to find one.

Does anyone know how to either solve option 1 iteration issue or a way to calculate the trace in the Keras backend?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this TF1 or TF2?

Comment: It is TF 1.12.0 with python3

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering, wouldn't this work?

```
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    batch_size = y_true.shape[0]
    X = K.log( K.dot(y_true, K.transpose(y_pred) ) )
    y = - tf.trace(X)
    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use - [appropriate Layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/lambda/)

```
tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    function, output_shape=None, mask=None, arguments=None, **kwargs
)
```

with function as callback (to use in it numpy.trace())... Can not test now...
I also can suppose, that you can try [Keras Models With TensorFlow NumPy](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/tensorflow_numpy_models/)